# Choose DirectX or OpenGL for Starling/stage3D

Tags: stage3d

The purpose is to test different texture formats. Can I specify DirectX or OpenGL for starling/stage3D? Otherwise, for textures like ETC, I have to test on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. It's OS specific. For win7 it's d3d9 and win8 d3d11. For other platforms it's openGL.

Comment: Thanks. Any official document which states the policy?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no official. But this answer gave me Chris Campbell when I was needed to debug shaders and asked how to choose dx11 backend.